# Axios Fetching Data But Returning Undefined

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have made an axios call, the then() and catch() perfectly log data, but when i return it , it sets the awaiting variable undefined

**Here is the axios file**

```
import axios from "axios";

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/",
});

export const loginManager = async (values) => {
  const response = await api
    .post("auth/login", values)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
      // that falls out of the range of 2xx
      console.log(error.response.data);
      console.log(error.response.status);
      console.log(error.response.headers);
return error.response.data
    } else if (error.request) {
      // The request was made but no response was received
      // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser 
      // and an instance of http.ClientRequest in node.js
      console.log(error.request);
return error.request
    } else {
      // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
      console.log('Error', error.message);
return error.message
    }
   
  });
  return response
};

export default api;
```

**Here is the component where i am calling it to**

```
const LoginPage = () => {
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
    },
    validate: globalLoginHandler,
    validateOnBlur: false,
    validateOnChange: false,
    onSubmit: async (values) => {
      toast.loading("Please Wait", { duration: 2000 });

    const data = await loginManager(values);
    },
  });
```

data must have response or error object

Comment: You don't return anything from the `.then` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using async/await you don't have to use .then()
You can simply log the response.data.
You can try this

```
const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/",
});

export const loginManager = async (values) => {
try{
const response = await api.post("auth/login", values);
  console.log(response?.data);
  return response?.data
} catch(err){
console.log(err);
}
  
};

export default api;
```